# select table using jquery without first column datas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get data from html table using jQuery.

In my situation, I want to get table without first columns.
Because I want to export table to excel file. 
But my first columns contains radio buttons. It is useless and painfully hard to remove it.

Anybody improve this mass.

**the table**

```
<table id="orders_table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> </th>
...
<th></th>
<tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio"<td>
...
<td>data<td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**the jQuery code I tried**

```
function getTable(){
    $("#orders_table");
    var html = "<table>";
    html += "<tr>";
    $.each($("#orders_table thead tr th "), function(i, d){//getting header
        if(i==0){}//do nothing
        else{
            html += "<th>" + $(this).html() + "</th>";
        }
    });

    html += "</tr>";
    $.each($("#orders_table tbody tr"), function(i, d){
        html += "<tr>";
        $.each($(d).find("td"), function(i2, d2){
            if(i2==0){} //do nothing
            if(i2==1){html += "<td>" + $(d2).html() + "</td>";}
            if(i2==2){html += "<td>" + $(d2).html() + "</td>";}
            if(i2==3){html += "<td>" + $(d2).html() + "</td>";}
            if(i2==4){html += "<td>" + $(d2).html() + "</td>";}
            if(i2==5){html += "<td>" + $(d2).html() + "</td>";}
            if(i2==6){html += "<td>" + $(d2).html() + "</td>";}
            if(i2==7){html += "<td>" + $(d2).html() + "</td>";}
            if(i2==8){html += "<td>" + $(d2).html() + "</td>";}
            if(i2==9){html += "<td>" + $(d2).html() + "</td>";}
            if(i2==10){html += "<td>" + $(d2).html() + "</td>";}
            if(i2==11){ html += "<td>" + $(d2).html() + "</td>";}
            if(i2==12){ html += "<td>" + $(d2).html() + "</td>";}
            if(i2==13){ html += "<td>" + $(d2).html() + "</td>";}
            if(i2==14){ html += "<td>" + $(d2).html() + "</td>";}
            if(i2==15){ html += "<td>" + $(d2).html() + "</td>";}
            if(i2==16){ html += "<td>" + $(d2).html() + "</td>";}
        });
        html += "</tr>";
    });


    html += "</table>";
    return html;
}
```

Comment: I just edited my post. actually, this code works, but when I export excel file, header datas are gone. And "td" contents looks like encoding problem. @ChristopherW

Comment: check if your html code syntax is correct. as **<td><input type="radio"<td>** , no closing tag for radio element. That can also affect the exported files;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps a better approach to removing the first column and returning the resulting html would be to clone the table, remove the first `td` element from each `tr`, and return the html from the clone

with something like http://jsfiddle.net/fKn6f/

```
var myclone = $("#orders_table").clone();
myclone.find( "tr > td:first-child" ).remove();

var html = myclone.html();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this jquery, update your `eq` depends on the index of your td

```
$("#orders_table tbody tr").each(function(i, d){
       var data1 =  $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
       var data2 =  $(this).find("td:eq(2)").text();
       var data3 =  $(this).find("td:eq(3)").text();
       ...
});
```